# как сделать условие для select max mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

мой запрос рабочий

```
select max(price ) as price from sina
```

но мне нужно что бы отбирало максимальную суму если в поле стоит top 1 или 2
то есть

id  price  top
1_20___1
2_10___1
3_30___2
4_50___2

так вот мне нужно получить 2 max сумы по двум параметрам top 1 и 2
id  price  top
1_20___1
4_50___2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, t.top, t.price from
(select top, max(price ) as price from sina where top in (1,2) group by top) t
join sina s on s.top=t.top and s.price=t.price;
```

Это в предположении, что для каждого top одна максимальная сумма. Другие способы описаны в статье ["Группировка в MySQL"](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте группировку

```
select max(price) as price, top from sina  group by top
```

Comment: да но мне нужно каждый результат вывести через as

Comment: @kursof Через какой AS? Сформулируйте вопрос